# Angular 5 - preload config file

Tags: angular

Angular 5 - Preload config file for cross application use

I was looking for an answer on how to pre-load a configuration file, to allow cross application usage, here's the answer - took initial implementation from: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AppConfigService } from './services/app-config.service';
export function init_app(configService: AppConfigService){
  // Load Config service before loading other components / services
  return () => {
    return configService.load();
  };
}

providers: [AppConfigService,
    {
      'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
      'useFactory': init_app,
      'deps': [AppConfigService],
      'multi': true,
    }
]
```

**app-config.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  config: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  load(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get('path/to/app-config.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => this.config = res)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }

  private handleError(error: HttpResponse<any> | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof HttpResponse) {
      const currentError: any = error;
      const body = currentError.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
     resolve(errMsg);
    });
  }
}
```

**Usage (from other Service / Component):**

```
import {AppConfigService} from './app-config.service';

constructor(private configService: AppConfigService) {
    console.log("configService: ",this.configService.config)
}
```

Comment: If this is an answer, you should post it as an answer to a question. Not as a question. Or post it as a blog post.

Answer (score 0):

I have a setup similar to yours, however, on my case the data is not persistent when calling a lazy load module.  I have to load it first into the session storage than I can used it. When I retrieve the data from the service, the "config" variable is null, I retrieve it from memory and assign it to the variable, once I do that it's available to the service.

```
//
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

    private config: any = null;
    private env: any = null;

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dataService: DataService) { }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public load(url?: string): Promise<any> {
        const defaultUrl: string = (url === undefined ? 'appConfig.json' : url);
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        const options: any = {
            url: defaultUrl,
            headers: headers,
            withCredentials: false,
            responseType: 'json'
        };

        return this.http.get(defaultUrl, options)
                .toPromise()
                .then((data: any) => {
                    this.config = data;
                    this.dataService.Push('ConfigData', this.config);
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791578/angular-5-preload-config-file
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private handleError(error: HttpResponse<any> | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof HttpResponse) {
            const currentError: any = error;
            const body = currentError.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve(errMsg);
        });
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public getConfig(key: any): any {

        if (null == this.config) {
            // pull from storage
            this.config = this.dataService.Get('ConfigData');
        }

        if (this.config && this.config.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            return this.config[key];
        }

        return null;
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

In my app.module.ts

```
//
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, LOCALE_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';
import { Ng2Webstorage } from 'ngx-webstorage';

import {ConfigService, SharedModule } from '@mylib/mylib-angular-library';

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
export function configServiceFactory(config: ConfigService) {
  return () => {
    return config.load();
  }
}

//  --------------------------------------------------------------------------

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
    , HttpClientModule
    , BrowserAnimationsModule    
    , Ng2Webstorage
    , SharedModule  // <-- ConfigService provided in this module
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],

  providers: [
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configServiceFactory, deps: [ConfigService], multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

What did I miss? Why do I need to store the configuration in the Session Storage.  For now this workaround works.

Comment: I would wait for the config request to be done, then set my services accordingly (also, not the ideal way...):

(MyService should implement setConfig method - to set config according to received config data )

export function configServiceFactory(config: ConfigService, myService:MyService) {
  return () => {
    const config = configService.load();
    config.then((data) => {
      myService.setConfig(data);
    })
    return config;
  };
}

Comment: `export function configServiceFactory(config: ConfigService, myService:MyService) {
  return () => {
    const config = configService.load();
    config.then((data) => {
      myService.setConfig(data);
    })
    return config;
  };
}`

Comment: Thank you Yonatan Ayalon for the help.  The issue turned out that I was injecting the service again when I loaded the lazy module, that created a new instance.  Once I removed it and only injected the service only in the parent module it works as expected.