# APP_INITIALIZER not blocking imported modules

Tags: angular

I have an Angular (v6.0.0) application which I'm attempting to set up with runtime configuration being pulled in during `APP_INITIALIZER`. I've read several articles (such as [this](https://robinraju.github.io/developer/2017-11-14-loading-external-config-in-angular/) and [this](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config/) and [this](https://davembush.github.io/where-to-store-angular-configurations/)) and SO questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791578/angular-5-preload-config-file) and have mostly gotten everything working.

I have the app calling a configuration service function to load the configuration when the application is bootstrapping (during `APP_INITIALIZER`). That all works perfectly. The problem is that other parts of the app are loading/initializing/their constructors are called before the configuration has loaded and thus can not use the configuration in the file. The following are excerpts of the app.module file:

```
function initConfig(configService: AppConfigService) {
    return () => configService.loadConfig();
}

...

@NgModule({
    imports: [AuthModule, SharedModule]
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initConfig,
            deps: [AppConfigService],
            multi: true
        },
        ...
    ]
})
```

and the AppConfigService file:

```
public loadConfig() {
    return this._http.get('./assets/app-config/config.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then((config: any) => {
            this.config = config;
        })
}
```

As you can see, the `loadConfig` function returns a promise, and the configuration is loaded (I've confirmed that).

However, I've tried to access the configuration in the AuthModule constructor (so I can pull configuration values needed for authenticating with a server) and in a service in the SharedModule (which is looking for the Sentry DSN in this case), and they both are run before the configuration is loaded. I'm sure there would be other examples, but this is what I've found so far.

I was under the impression that nothing in the application would load before `APP_INITIALIZER` has resolved, but apparently that's not the case. Is there something I'm missing to complete this? Is there something I can do to cause all other modules to wait for the configuration to load before initializing? If not, it basically defeats the purpose of runtime configuration.

Comment: Are you add in providers the "AppConfigService" in your app.module.ts and ONLY in this module ?(not put in providers in other module that the main, else you will have two or more instance of the service)

Comment: Well, the `AppConfigService` has the `providedIn: root` option set, and it's not listed in any `providers` array in the entire app.

Comment: @pjlamb12, can you create a simple demo that mimicks your setup with stackblitz? I'll take a look

Comment: @MaxWizardK I will try to reproduce it. The hard part was trying to figure out what services it did this in and which ones it didn't. But I'll comment back here when I've figured out how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MaxWizardK I have been trying to reproduce this but have been unable to so far.

Comment: @pjlamb12, sorry, can't help without a reproducible demo

Comment: @MaxWizardK I finally was able to reproduce it. Check out this StackBlitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/runtime-config-loader-demo-not-loaded. In this case, I have an error handler service that's also provided in the app.module file. In that error handler service, I may need some configuration (like the Sentry DSN, for example) so I need the config service injected. But when I do that, the config is not available in the constructor unless I use the subject and subscribe to it.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

I recently faced the issue that you were facing. Unfortunately, as may already know, APP_INITIALIZER doesn't block the imports of modules. You can use the global window object to attach your configuration data. This way the data is accessible globally across your application.

```
public loadConfig() {
    return this._http.get('./assets/app-config/config.json')
        .toPromise()
        .then((config: any) => {
            window['appConfigData'] = config;
            this.config = config;
        })
}
```

In your service that is part of SharedModule you can simply access the config data from the window object.

```
constructor() {
  ..
  ..
    const configData = window['appConfigData'];
}
```

Comment: Not working. Getting error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.